# How can I maintain 'box7' div styling when adding <HREF> URLs to image?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I have a fancy template that I grabbed for a simple interactive image menu here: https://kylebb.com/index.html#portfolio

When I add  URLs around the images inside there though, they seem to lose the "box7" div styling. The .box7:hover > img styling as well as the .box7 > img styling seem to get removed if I tag the URL around the img.

Why is this and how do I keep it so it appears as it does now, but the images link elsewhere?

HREF tags around the image and the entire div do strange things to the sizing of the image and the entire div and messing about with the styling is not working.

Comment: What does 'href around an image' mean? Are you talking about wrapping images in anchor elements? Please show us code within your question, not on an external site, and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you've added an anchor (a) element between the .box7 element and the img element then that > will stop the styling being applied because it is saying 'img that is a direct child of...'

Comment: Right - so how do I not stop it from applying styling because it's a direct child, if that makes sense? Or how do I achieve / keep the effect, while adding a hyperlink on the image?

 <div class="box7">
    <a href="https://kylebb.com/portfolio/branding.html"><img src="img/port_thumb_branding.jpg"></a>
   <span>Branding & Marketing</span>
  </div>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is being changed to add an anchor element around the img element.

This means that the selectors:

```
.box7:hover > img  

.box7 > img
```

will no longer have any effect because they are both saying select any img that is a direct child of an element with class .box7

You will need to replace all such with e.g.

```
.box7:hover > a > img  

.box7 > a > img
```